# Assets + Low Variables // Limiting and Ordering By "Random"

Tags: assets, low-variables

Trying to do something I feel should be very simple to execute, but I cannot for the life of me seem to get it to work.

Here's my template snippet:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_home_featured_images" limit="1" orderby="random"}
{exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" height="500" width="1200" crop="yes" attributes="style='width:1200px;height:500px;' alt='ALT'"}
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

I've got two images loaded into a Low Variable which has a fieldtype set to Assets.

Instead of getting just one random image selected, the same image keeps coming up over and over.

Running EE 2.7.0, Low Vars 2.3.5 and Assets 2.1.4. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!
~
Wes

Answer (score 1):

Check out low's random addon - FREE.  http://gotolow.com/addons/low-random/docs

Comment: Welcome to EE StackExchange.  It will help if you check off that this is the accepted answer.  Best regards Chris